# How can I write  subscript E in TeX?

Tags: symbols

How can we write [image: the below image] (an 'm') and [image: n_E] in TeX format?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you give us some smaller illustration example? :-) Please provide a minimal document and tell us, if you use pdfLaTeX or others. And edit your title to something that will help other users in future. Like this, people will be happy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using texmaker in which I want to type M_E as shown above. Please tell us that which type of this script.

Answer (score 16):

Your "M"-symbol looks like a fracture letter. The most typical way is to use the command `\mathfrak{}` from the package `amsfonts`. You have to use this in math-mode.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % which loads amsfonts

\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{M}_E$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The unicode for this symbol is [U+1D510](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d510/index.htm). When using Lua- or XeLaTeX, you could load it e.g. with `\symbol{"1D510}` from `fontspec` or `\mfrakM` from `unicode-math`.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
    \toprule
    Font & Example\\
    \midrule
    Latin Modern & $\mfrakM_E$\\
    Asana & \setmathfont{Asana Math}$\mfrakM_E$\\
    XITS & \setmathfont{XITS Math}$\mfrakM_E$\\
    TeX Gyre Pagella & \setmathfont{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}$\mfrakM_E$\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

Regarding your second question. You can make this image as follows:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}

\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\begin{document}
    $\scriptscriptstyle\mathfrak{N}_E$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are very welcome. Please click the check mark on the left if you want to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Please tell us how can we type the second image n_E ? Is this also a fracture letter?

Comment: @user114673 See my updated answer!

Comment: Just a note to remind that `amsfonts` is also loaded by `amssymb`.